# How to allow uploaded image brightness and contrast to be edited with a UI like a slider?

Tags: 7, media

Many sites, like eBay to give a well-known example, allow users to edit images they upload with a slider or buttons to increase or decrease brightness and contrast. When the UI is used, a new image is (generally) generated server-side and AJAX-loaded in place, until the user is happy and saves a particular version.

In theory, Drupal is capable of all this. GD and ImageMagick support brightness and contrast adjustments and there are plenty of modules built on Image Styles that allow image editting (Imagecache Actions, Manual Crop).

Some even imply they support something like this, for example [imagick](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagick):

> - Modulate
>
>   - Brightness
>   - Saturation
>   - Hue

...and [Imagecache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions):

> - Brighten/Darken
> - ...
> - Custom Actions - Execute your own PHP/GD code in the middle of an imagecache generation process. Requires some familiarity with imageAPI internals.

[Image Effect Kit](https://www.drupal.org/node/2113769) also has brightness and contrast under its "filter" options.

However, I can't find any combination of settings, modules and configuration that gives any control over anything like this to the user, or that could be attached to a UI control.

---

It's also possible to edit an image purely in the client side, using a [JS/Canvas editor like CanmanJS then sending the Base64 data to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654031/saving-images-after-altering-them-by-camanjs-plugin), but I'm not aware of any existing Drupal integration for this or way to pipe this image data into Drupal's filefield/image style system. I've found a couple of modules for exporting images as Base64 ([Image Base64 Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_base64), [Data URI creator](https://www.drupal.org/project/data_uri_creator)) but not for importing them as such.

---

I've seen [Image Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageeditor) module which pipes in 3rd party image editors like Avery, but they're excessive for my needs and I'd prefer not to rely on a 3rd party service. The only one I can see that uses a local library not a hosted 3rd party service is [PaintWeb](http://mihai.sucan.ro/paintweb/trunk/demos/demo1.html) which seems to be only basic drawing tools, not brightness or contrast, and an SVG editor.

Can this be done in Drupal?